# postgis environments changed with macport selfupdate

Tags: postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, macports, postgis

Last month I've installed PostgresSql 8.4.1 and Postgis 1.4 via macports on my Mac with Leopard(10.5), and everything just worked fine. I then updated to Snow Leopard(10.6) and still everything was working fine. Yesterday I've tried to install Gimp with macports, the installation failed. So I did a "port selfupdate" which seemed to destroyed parts of my Postgis installation.

When a try to access a table with geometry columns within my database I receive the following error:

ERROR: could not load library "/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/postgis-1.4.so": dlopen(/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/postgis-1.4.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/postgis-1.4.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
SQL Status:58P01

The other non-postgis tables are still accessible!

I've checked with "port installed" if postgis was maybe uninstalled, and received the following list:
...
postgis @1.4.0_1+postgresql84 (active)
  postgresql84 @8.4.0_0
  postgresql84 @8.4.1_0 (active)
  postgresql84-server @8.4.0_0 (active)
...

I assume that the missing tables are still on the disk, but are not referenced correctly. Is there a way to search on the hard-disk for the database, and maybe change the reference?

Answer (score 1):

When you upgraded from 10.5 to 10.6, did you reinstall MacPorts and reinstall your ports? MacPorts (and the ports it manages) are heavily tied to the version of the OS under which it is installed. If you upgrade the OS, you should reinstall MacPorts (and your ports). More information is available in the [MacPorts migration FAQ](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

Comment: It turns out with my new laptop I grabbed the wrong disk set for Xcode. When I installed the correct (newest) version, everything worked. thanks mipadi